# What will happen when deno will come

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, deno

What will happen with react or webpack, which use node js, when deno comes.
Will Node.js and Express die?

Comment: First time I've heard of deno. Checked the tag's description - it's build on V8. That's the same engine behind Node.js, so I don't see a big problem with transition being possible. Sure, it might not be a drop in replacement (although, it'd be smarter for deno to be designed as a drop in replacement) but surely the community around these tools is large and mature enough to handle a wrapper or whatever to let them be used with a different runtime.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I might be completely wrong, but this appears to be not a programming question?

Comment: @VLAZ: Node and Deno were created by the same guy. I think that he created Deno to fix what he had done wrong in Node. Just look at the name of those 2 things :D

Answer (score 3):

Even if Deno ends up becoming more popular than or supercedes NodeJS, NodeJS and its other dependencies are not going to disappear.  If Deno does take off, I suspect you will eventually start seeing either new versions or forks of frameworks that relied on NodeJS being converted to Deno.  But even if Deno goes viral and becomes the "new thing", that transition is not going to happen overnight and suddenly leave all the other frameworks behind.